# UIImageView contentMode Top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, contentmode

I've got an image that I need crop. To do this, I wanted to use the contentMode (set it to Top/TopLeft instead of Aspect Fit) but when I'm doing this, the image go back to it's real size (and not the size I gave to it). So my question is :

How to crop the bottom of my image retaining its size ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to set the `rect` for the `imageView`

`imageView` is the instance of `UIImageView`

Let the rectangle to be cropped is `croppedRect`

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageView.image CGImage], croppedRect);
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Comment: That seems to be what I need but it behaves strangely. If i want to crop the bottom, am I supposed to give him a rect like '0, 0, width, height - x' or 'Xpos, Ypos, width, size - 128'. I tried those cases and no one worked..

Comment: What strange? The code is working fine for me. See my edited code

Comment: Yeah, I guessed the mistake but it zoom on my image and not showing the right rect. Moreover, it seems that x and y values are reversed.

Comment: Image is cropped and it is looking like zoom effect because the size of UIImageView is constant.

Comment: So i just have to resize my image frame according to this ?

Comment: resizing your image frame will show unknown behavior in your UI. And moreover, its not a zoom effect, its just cropping

Comment: Does it crop the real-sized image or the image of the size I gave to it ?